# setTimeout to delay the pop up to show

Tags: jquery

I need help to delay the pop up to show after 5 seconds when landed on the page. This is the code I used. I am still new with Jquery so any help with do. Thanks!

```js
/*$(window).load(function(){
     $("#popup-delay").modal('show');
    
    });*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie("popup_1_2") == null) {
    setTimeout(delay, 10000);
    $("#popup-delay").modal('show');
    $.cookie('popup_1_2', '2');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="popup" class="modal fade" id="popup-delay" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <div class="close-btn">
          <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h2>
                This is a test</h2>
              <button aria-label="Close" class="close-btn mini-new-buttons" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" value="No Thanks">No Thanks</button></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>[**setTimeout(function[, delay]);**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) The setTimeout() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin (and successor to Window.setTimeout()) sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.... **[function]** Required.
>   The function that will be executed ... **[delay]** Optional. The number
>   of milliseconds to wait before executing the code. If omitted, the
>   value 0 is used</sup>

To check for window load or document is ready you can use

```
// Pure Javascript
window.onload = function(){
    // code here
}
```

**OR**

```
// JQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
   // code here
});
```

Up to the above then your code should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.cookie("popup_1_2") == null){
       setTimeout(function(){
           $("#popup-delay").modal('show');
           $.cookie('popup_1_2','2');
       }, 5000); // 5000 is a 5 seconds
    }
});
```